# How to use promise in npm sitemap package?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, sitemap

I am trying to use v5.1.0 of [the npm `sitemap` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) to create a sitemap index.

I already have this working code that just creates a sitemap:

```
const { createSitemap } = require('sitemap')
function getSitemap(hostname, urls) {
    const s = createSitemap({
        hostname, urls,
        cacheTime: config.SITEMAP_CACHE_TIME_SECS * 1000,
    });
    return s.toXML(function(err, xml) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(xml);
    });
}
exports.routes = function(app) {
    app.get("/sitemap.xml", function(req, res) {
        Promise.all([
            entity.Template.allPublicShowcaseURLs(),
            entity.User.allPublicShowcaseURLs(),
        ]).then(([showcase_urls, profile_urls]) => {
            return getSitemap(config.URL, showcase_urls.concat(profile_urls));
        })
        .then(serveXML(res))
        .catch(utils.fail(req, res));
    });
};
```

Now I'm trying to change it to create a sitemap index, following [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap#auto-creating-sitemap-and-index-files-from-one-large-list) (which isn't really very clear).

This is what I'm trying instead:

```
const { createSitemapsAndIndex } = require('sitemap')
function getSitemap(hostname, urls) {
    const smi = createSitemapsAndIndex({
        hostname, urls,
        cacheTime: config.SITEMAP_CACHE_TIME_SECS * 1000,
        targetFolder: require('os').tmpdir()
    });
    console.log('smi', smi)
    return smi.toXML(function(err, xml) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(xml);
    });
}
```

But this fails with `smi.toXML is not a function`. The console shows that `smi` is `Promise { <pending> }` at that point. I think perhaps this function returns a Promise because it wants to write something to the filesystem(?). I've been [trying to read the source](https://github.com/ekalinin/sitemap.js/blob/master/lib/sitemap-index.ts) but can't really follow it.

I guess I need to resolve the Promise, get whatever it returns, and then turn that into XML - but how?

Comment: `return createSitemapsAndIndex(…).then(smi => smi.toXML())` maybe?

Comment: From that I just get `TypeError: smi.toXML is not a function`, thanks anyway.